# Highlighting default text input in sweetAlert

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I have a [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io) that allows text input, and I give it a default value. I'd like this default value to be highlighted when the alert pops up, so that the user can immediately overwrite it if needed. Here's an example:

[image]

And here is the function that I call with the sweetAlert options:

```
window.sweetPrompt = function (title, message, callback, input, keepopen, allowOutsideClick, allowEscapeKey) {
    sweetAlert({
        title: title,
        text: message,
        input: 'text',
        confirmButtonColor: "#428bca",
        preConfirm: function(text) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                if (!keepopen) {
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    callback(text);
                }
            });
        },
        inputValidator: function(text) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                if (text) {
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    reject('Cannot be empty!');
                }
            });
        },
        inputValue: input,
        showCancelButton: true,
        reverseButtons: true,
        allowOutsideClick: allowOutsideClick,
        allowEscapeKey: allowEscapeKey
    }).then(callback, function(dismiss){});
};
```

How would I go about doing this (if it's possible) ? I thought about using jQuery but I'm not sure how to get the reference to the sweetAlert dialogue.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
Swal.fire({
  input: 'text',
  inputValue: 'input value',
  didOpen: () => {
    Swal.getInput().select()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

PS. Please note that SweetAlert2 and SweetAlert are two different projects with slight differences in API.

SweetAlert2 documentation: https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Comment: Why don't you use input.select() instead of input.setSelectionRange(0, input.value.length) ? It gives the same effect I think..